# Show that this mapping is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

**Show that the map *v* = [*v*]<sub>*E*</sub> → [*v*]<sub>*B*</sub> for all *v* ∈ R<sup>n</sup> defines a linear transformation *T*<sub>*B*</sub> : R<sup>n</sup> → R<sup>n</sup>.**

***B*** = {*b*<sub>*1*</sub>, *b*<sub>*2*</sub>, *b*<sub>*3*</sub>,...,*b*<sub>*n*</sub>} is a basis of R<sup>n</sup>. Any vector *v* ∈ R<sup>n</sup> can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of ***B***: *v* = c<sub>1</sub>b<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>b<sub>2</sub> + ... + c<sub>n</sub>b<sub>n</sub>. The *n*-tuple (c<sub>1</sub> to c<sub>n</sub>) is called the representation of v in ***B***, denoted by [*v*]<sub>***B***</sub>. *v*, a vector in **R**<sup>n</sup> can be viewed as *v* represented in the standard basis **E** = {*e*<sub>1</sub>, *e*<sub>2</sub>,...,*e*<sub>n</sub>}.

Comment: beware: one thing is a change of basis and another is a linear transformation

Comment: if ${\cal{B}}(R^n)$ is the set of bases of $R^n$ a *basis change* is a map ${\cal{B}}(R^n)\to{\cal{B}}(R^n)$. A linear transformation $R^n\to R^n$ is another map with different domain-codomain than of a basis change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(\mathbf v_E) = \mathbf v_B$.  Can you show that the map $f$ satisfies the [definition of a linear map](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Definition_and_first_consequences), i.e. that $f(\mathbf u + \mathbf v) = f(\mathbf u) + f(\mathbf v)$ and that $f(\alpha\,\mathbf u) = \alpha\, f(\mathbf u)$?  (Hint: You should be able to do this just by looking at the definition of $\mathbf v_B$.)

---

OK, let me unpack that a little:

Given a basis $B = \{\mathbf b_1, \mathbf b_2, \dotsc, \mathbf b_n\}$, let $\mathbf u = c_1 \mathbf b_1 + \dotsb + c_n \mathbf b_n$ and $\mathbf v = d_1 \mathbf b_1 + \dotsb + d_n \mathbf b_n$, so that, by definition, $\mathbf u_B = (c_1, \dotsc, c_n)$ and $\mathbf v_B = (d_1, \dotsc, d_n)$.  From this, it directly follows that $\mathbf u + \mathbf v = (c_1 + d_1) \mathbf b_1 + \dotsb + (c_n + d_n) \mathbf b_n$, and thus that $(\mathbf u + \mathbf v)_B = \mathbf u_B + \mathbf v_B$.

By a similar argument, you can show that $(\alpha\, \mathbf u)_B = \alpha\, (\mathbf u_B)$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.  Together, these results prove that the map $\mathbf v \mapsto \mathbf v_B$ is linear, as the question asks.

(In the question you quoted, the vector $\mathbf v$ is identified with its standard representation $\mathbf v_E = (a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$ given by $\mathbf v = a_1 \mathbf e_1 + \dotsb + a_n \mathbf e_n$, where $E = \{\mathbf e_1, \dotsc, \mathbf e_n\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$.  If you want to distinguish between $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf v_E$, and specifically show that the map $\mathbf v_E \mapsto \mathbf v_B$ is linear, it's enough to show that $\mathbf v_E \mapsto \mathbf v$ is also (trivially) linear, and then apply the lemma that the composition of two linear maps is linear.)

Comment: I don't really see where to begin though. Isn't the definition of **v**<sub>*B*</sub> just the scalars c<sub>1</sub> to c<sub>n</sub>?

Comment: Yes, it is. What should happen to those scalars if you add another vector to $\mathbf v$?  Can you prove this?

Comment: and since the question is about mapping *v*<sub>*E*</sub> to *v*<sub>*B*</sub>, doesn't that mean it's mapping from the identity matrix E-scalars to the C-scalars? That bit has me thoroughly confused.

Comment: The "E-scalars" are trivially related to the components of the vector, trivially enough that they can essentially be identified. *That* should not be the difficult bit, here.

Comment: Ps. You may want to take a look at how you can [write math expressions using MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here.

Comment: I expanded my answer a little; does that help any?

Comment: A little. Is (u+v)B = [U]B + [V]B supposed to be the same as T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)?

Or in general, is the representation in basis B the same as the transformation T?

Comment: Yes, $T(u) = [u]_B$ by definition (and I left out the square brackets from my answer, because I didn't want to clutter up the notation).  I didn't actually notice that the problem you quoted had named the map $u \mapsto u_B$ as $T$ (or $T_B$, to be exact), which is why I decided to call it $f$ in the first part of my answer.

Comment: Ooohh, I think most of my confusion was from not knowing T(u)=[u]B. Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: do you know any references that explain how a basis change can be consider as a endomorphism?

Answer (score 0):

Create a matrix $M$ whose columns are the $b_{i}$, then $T(u)=Mu$ performs the transformation. It is now easy to show that $T$ has the properties of a linear transformation.

Comment: This'll work, but requires showing that the matrix whose columns are the basis vectors $B$ is invertible (and that its inverse is the desired matrix $M$). It seems to me that just directly applying the definition of linearity is easier in this case.